# Purpose of the .htaccess files in the Drupal files directory?

Tags: .htaccess

Besides the *.htaccess* file in the Drupal site main folder, I've found a .htaccess file in the `sites\default\files` folder, and further such files some sub-folders of `sites\default\files` folder (for example, in `sites\default\files\private`).

My question can actually be broken down into two separate questions:

1. How would you define in simple words the purpose of both the main *.htaccess* files, and the others under `sites\default\files` (I assume there aren't anymore *.htaccess* files?).
2. Is the only reason for splitting the *Python syntax* to different *.htaccess* files is to not make a single huge file? Or there are other reasons?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first .htaccess file in the root directory is for routing and to override any PHP related settings.

The second .htaccess file under sites/default/files is for security purpose, to avoid any file injection. This folder is Drupal's main upload folder.

The upload folder can be moved in different places, or in a multi site setup you could have more than one folder. That is why they provided a separate .htaccess instead of putting everything in one place.